# Finding shortest path distances in a graph containing at most two negative edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path

I am given a directed graph where each edge has a cost.Taking advantage of the fact that there are at most two negative edges in the graph, my goal is to find shortest path distances from a given node s to all the nodes in V. The time complexity of the algorithm should be `O(|E| + |V|*log|V|)`, so I think I need to apply Dijkstra's algorithm.

I am guessing that I need to translate my given graph somehow to a new graph with non-negative weights that a shortest path from s to v in this graph will be equivalent to the required shortest path in the given graph.. or maybe I need to modify Dijkstra's algorithm?

I am struggling right now. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: assume U and V are negative edge,solve problem in 4 state:
1- the path are not contain U and V.
2- the path are contain U and not contain V.
3- the path are contain V and not contain U.
4- the path are contain U and v.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Dijkstra's algorithm is greedy, it won't work with negative weights. You need some other algorithm like [the **Bellman-Ford Algorithm**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm) for this purpose.

But, if you still want to use Dijkstra's algorithm, there is a known way. In this method, you need to reassign costs, so that all become positive.

For that you can check out **Johnson's Algorithm**. Johnson's algorithm consists of the following steps (taken from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%27s_algorithm)):

1. First, a new node q is added to the graph, connected by zero-weight edges to each of the other nodes.
2. Second, the Bellman–Ford algorithm is used, starting from the new vertex q, to find for each vertex v the minimum weight h(v) of a path from q to v. If this step detects a negative cycle, the algorithm is terminated.
3. Next the edges of the original graph are reweighted using the values computed by the Bellman–Ford algorithm: an edge from u to v, having length w(u,v), is given the new length w(u,v) + h(u) − h(v).
4. Finally, q is removed, and Dijkstra's algorithm is used to find the shortest paths from each node s to every other vertex in the reweighted graph.

Answer (score 1):

**Just some definitions to start:**

- Let the negative edges be `n1 = (n1s, n1e)` (i.e. from vertex `n1s` to vertex `n1e`)
  and `n2 = (n2s, n2e)`.
- Define the start and end vertex of the shortest path we want to find as `s` and `e` respectively.

**The basic idea:**

Run Dijkstra's algorithm multiple times for each combination of the starting vertex and each end vertex of the negative-weight edges as the starting point and the end vertex and each start vertex of the negative-weight edges as the ending point, and use these values to find the actual shortest path.

**The algorithm:**

- Use Dijkstra's algorithm to determine the following shortest paths, all excluding both negative edges:

  ```
  se   = s -> e                  // shortest path from s to e
  sn1  = s -> n1s                // shortest path from s to n1
  sn2  = s -> n2s                // shortest path from s to n2
  ne1  = n1e -> e                // shortest path from n1 to e
  n1n2 = n1e -> n2s              // shortest path from n1 to n2
  ne2  = n2e -> e                // shortest path from n2 to e
  n2n1 = n2e -> n1s              // shortest path from n2 to n1
  ```
- Now simply calculate the minimum of:

  ```
  se                             // s to e
  sn1 + n1 + ne1                 // s to n1 to e
  sn2 + n2 + ne2                 // s to n2 to e
  sn1 + n1 + n1n2 + n2 + ne2     // s to n1 to n2 to e
  sn2 + n2 + n2n1 + n1 + ne1     // s to n2 to n1 to e
  ```

Since there's a constant 7 runs of Dijkstra's algorithm,
the running time will be `O(7(|E| + |V| log |V|))` = `O(|E| + |V| log |V|)`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. My goal is to find shortest path distances from a given node s to ALL the nodes in V. What is e (end vertex) in this case?