# Finding shortest path distances from a given node s to ALL the nodes in V in a graph with two negative edges

Tags: algorithm, graph, dijkstra, shortest-path, bellman-ford

I have a follow-up question on this:
[Finding shortest path distances in a graph containing at most two negative edges](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21556978/finding-shortest-path-distances-in-a-graph-containing-at-most-two-negative-edges)

Ranveer's solution looks great, but it is not fast enough because I need O(|E| + |V|*log|V|) fast algorithm.

I guess Dukeling's solution works great. It makes sense and it operates in the same running time of Dijkstra's algorithm.

However, my goal is to find shortest path distances from a given node s to ALL the nodes in V.
If I apply Dukeling's algorithm by setting all the nodes in V as end vertex e, I will need to run it |V| - 1 times. Then, the running time will be O(|V||E| + |V^2|*log|V|).

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You only need to run it once: Dijkstra's finds the shortest paths from a source node to ALL other vertexes.

Answer (score 3):

Dijkstra's algorithm, in its original form, finds all the shortest paths from a source node to all other nodes in the graph.

You have (at least) two options for your problem:

1. Use [Bellman - Ford](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bellman%E2%80%93Ford_algorithm). It's not as slow as its big-oh would suggest, at least not necessarily. Make sure you implement it like you would a [BF search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breadth-first_search): using a [FIFO queue](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FIFO). This means you will insert a node into the queue every time the distance to it is updated, and only if it isn't already in the queue. Other optimizations are also possible, but this should already give you a fast algorithm in practice;
2. Use [Dijkstra's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dijkstra%27s_algorithm), but modified similarly to Bellman - Ford: the default Dijkstra's never inserts a node twice into the priority queue. Make sure you reinsert nodes if you have updated the distance to them. This will deal with negative cost edges. It essentially makes the algorithm closer to the Bellman - Ford described above, but using a priority queue instead of a FIFO queue. This will also get you closer to your desired complexity.

Comment: After thinking for hours, I ended up agreeing with Dukeling's solution. Do you see anything wrong in Dukeling's answer?

Comment: @user1885433 - yes, it's overly complicated, unproven and untested. It also seems to assume a single destination node, and you want all, which means you will either have to run it `|V| - 1` times or adapt it. Why are the solutions I suggested not appropriate for your problem?

Comment: I did not mean that your suggested solutions are not appropriate for my problem. I googled about the modification of Dijkstra's algorithm to handle negative edges and it seems that it is a reasonable solution. The only thing I am concerned with is that it takes exponential time in the worst case, which is slower than I want.

Comment: Go to http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/44sp/. It says, "The version implemented in DijkstraSP.java (which allows a vertex to be enqueued more than once) is correct in the presence of negative edge weights (but no negative cycles) but its running time is exponential in the worst case."

Comment: @|V|ad - It turns out that there is no problem at all with Dukeling's solution...

Comment: @user1885433 - in the absence of negative cost cycles, each node can be enqued `O(n)` times in the worst case, so not exponential. As for Dukeling's solution, if you have proven that it is correct and it fits your needs, that is great. Best of luck to you!